# LM386 as pre-amplifier for electret capsule

Tags: audio, preamp, electret

Although I know the LM386 is intended as a power audio amplifier, I wish to know if it can be used as a pre-amplifier for an electret microphone capsule, as I intend to use it for that purpose. If yes, can you suggest basic schematics?

Comment: What is the input referred noise value for the 386? I suspect it will be poor and, because I've never seen anyone do this, I expect there are no basic schematics.

Comment: There are many circuit diagrams on the internet showing how to use an LM386 as a microphone preamplifier. In general, the LM386 is a poor choice for a microphone amplifier. It "works" in the same sense that a garbage truck can be used as a race car - you can drive it around the race track but you won't be winning any races. This site isn't about recommending circuits, it is about designing circuits. If you refer to a specific LM386 microphone amplifier circuit, you will get advice on how to use it and why it is bad.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.